# How to cast a keyboard event

Tags: java, keyboard, action, listener

Where it says `**spacebarpressed**`, I want to cast an event:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, AWTException{

    final Robot robot = new Robot();

    robot.delay(2000);

    while(true)
    {
        if( **spacebarpressed** ) {
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

            robot.delay(50);
        }
        else {
            robot.delay(50);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check if spacebar is pressed? If that's so, you need an inner private class that implements `KeyListener`, but you need to hook it up to a `JFrame` however... I don't know about any other way.

```
private class Key
    implements KeyListener
{
    private boolean spacebarPressed = false;

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
        {
            spacebarPressed = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
        {
            spacebarPressed = false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isSpacebarPressed()
    {
        return spacebarPressed;
    }
}
```

And then just call `isSpacebarPressed()` in your while loop to check.

Comment: when i put the code sub class under my class declaration and then use "while(isSpacebarPressed())" it says I need to create the method isSpacebarPressed, what can i do about this?

Comment: Make sure you create it's instance... "Key keyObject = new Key()", and then you can use "keyObject.isSpacebarPressed()". But before all this you need to hook it up to a JFrame, and as I can see, your main method throws AWTException so you must be using UI, therefore hook that instance to your window ("jframeObject.addKeyListener(keyObject);") to make it update.

Comment: i want's me to make keyObject static, what did i messed up?