# Default close shortcut does not work

Tags: java, swing, default, shortcut

The default close shortcut (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> on Mac) doesn't work on this program i coded in java, do you know why?

I am an absolute beginner and would be glad if you helped me!

The code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, AWTException{

    final Robot robot = new Robot();

    robot.delay(2000);

    while(true)
    {
        {
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

        robot.delay(50);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be because Java is trying to be as cross-platform (or platform-independent) as it can be. You could make your own closing shortcut, using the `Key` class explained in your previous questions (specifically: [How to cast a keyboard event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705664/how-to-cast-a-keyboard-event)). However, I don't think you could detect mac-specific keys, unless you dive into JNI (Java Native Interface), but if you are a beginner I wouldn't recommend it just yet.

For example, say you would like the shortcut to be <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>. Add another field in your `Key` class:

```
private boolean ctrlPressed = false;
```

Then, make a pressing check:

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    //Previous code


    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL)
    {
        ctrlPressed = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
    //Previous code


    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL)
    {
        ctrlPressed = false;
    }
}
```

And finally, the Q part:

```
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
{
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Q && ctrlPressed)
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: if I add the q part in the inner Key class does it background-check automatically or do i need to add something that calls it in the while(true) loop?

Comment: It checks "automatically", yes, because it is called by an AWT thread, you don't need to do anything, just hook your Key object to your JFrame object.